# Django installation first time

Tags: django, virtualenv

I started learning DJango for the first time. I have some amount of basic knowledge of python but DJango is first for me. I started with the [documentation page of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/), but i am getting stuck where it asks for

> python manage.py syncdb

At present i do not have any database, so i assumed that SQLite comes with django. Not sure how to go ahead? Also i have downloaded the virtualenv-1.7.1.2 and installed it as well with,

> python virtualenv.py ENV

I am following this [video tutorial](http://gigantuan.s3.amazonaws.com/screencasts/django1.webm), it asks me to use,

> sudo pip install virtualenv

But when i write the above code, the output is,

> sudo: pip: command not found

Help me out!!

Comment: If you just want to learn django, I suggest just ignore the virtualenv/pip things.

Comment: If you are running ubuntu, sudo apt-get install python-pip. And then run the sudo pip command again

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Do not use sudo with virtualenv** this is the easiest way to multiple problems later.

Begin by installing `virtualenv` - `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`

Next, ***as your normal user*** run the following commands:

1. `$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django-env`
2. `$ source django-env/bin/activate`
3. `(django-env)$ pip install django`
4. `(django-env)$ django-admin.py startproject myproject`
5. `(django-env)$ cd myproject`
6. `(django-env)/myproject$ nano settings.py`
7. In `settings.py`, after `'ENGINE:'` type `'django.db.backends.sqlite3',` (don't forget the comma)
8. In `settings.py`, after the `'NAME:'` type `'site.db',` (again, don't forget the comma)
9. Save the file, and exit the editor
10. `(django-env)/myproject$ python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: sudo: apt-get: command not found

This is the error message when i try to execute the first statement. And i am using Mac

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I was able to install on my linux but Mac OS X i am still not able to do that

Comment: If you are on a mac, you can use `sudo easy_install virtualenv`

Comment: sudo easy_install pip    # installs pip
sudo pip install -U pip

Given by @Keith works well thanks

Comment: what is the issue with using pip instead of easy_install??

Comment: You need to install pip first, easy_install usually comes with Python as part of setuptools.

Comment: but you said not to use sudo with virtualenv, what is the problem in using that? I am not doubting you just want to learn for my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using linux, you should be able to get the Python setuptools from your distribution's repositories. Once installed, type

```
sudo easy_install pip    # installs pip
sudo pip install -U pip  # upgrades pip to most recent version
```

From there, you can continue to follow the tutorial.

If you're not using linux, download Python setuptools from PyPI. [Python setuptools [PyPI]](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

For OS X, the above should still work in the terminal. On windows, you may have to do the above from an elevated command prompt (not sure), but without the `sudo` command at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution for Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is included with Python 2.5+. You should be able to edit your settings.py file with the relevant database settings (database type and filename, see official docs for details), and your database will then be created upon next running syncdb.

There is a great tutorial on working with virtualenvs and Django at http://bartek.im/blog/2010/07/13/django-environment.html

I also highly recommend virtualenv-burrito to simplify the installation (and updating) process for virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper: https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito

If you are still facing issues, do you get any errors when running syncdb at present? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexbile way, IMO, of installing w/o old setuptools, is

1. download virtualenv
   `$ curl -O http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.1.2.tar.gz`
2. extract
   `tar xzf virtualenv-1.7.1.2.tar.gz`
3. use the version of Python you want to run Django to install virtualenv, for example
   `$ python2.7 virtualenv-1.7.1.2/virtualenv.py --distribute ~/env`
4. enter env in which the pip has been already installed
   `$ source ~/env/bin/activate`
5. install packages in current env instead of polluting global space or needing sudo
   `pip install Django`
   Then Django will be installed to path like `~/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django`.
6. Or you could
   `pip install -e svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk`
   to install latest trunk code of Django, and the source will be in `~/env/src/django/django`. Then you are free to read the source or modify it. Also, you could have full documents by `make html` in `~/env/src/django/docs`

Things installed by the above method are totally local, you don't need to type sudo or take the risk of messing up paths such as `/usr/local/lib`, even more, you could then be able to install multiple versions of Django or Python w/o affect each other!

Furthermore, you could try virtualenvwrapper.