# How to reenter a pre-existing django app

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I recently set up a Django app using virtualenv with the [help of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066681/django-installation-first-time#comment12885400_10066681). Now i closed my terminal and trying to again get in but the same commands are not running.

How to do I reenter my app? I am on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: It depends on what docs you were following, but you're probably looking for `source ~/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`

Comment: ya i did execute source `django-env/bin/activate` is that correct?

Comment: Yes, assuming your virtualenv is called `django-env` and is in the current directory (eg, you see django-env when you run `ls`). It can be helpful to specify the full paths to virtualenvs so you don't have to think about what directory you're in when figuring out what you need to pass to `source`.

Comment: As a sidenote, you'd probably find [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) useful.

Comment: Thanks thats the answer @AdamKG

Comment: Could u place it in the answer dialogue @AdamKG

Comment: Y have I been downvoted for this comment? Y am I not being allowed to ask questions? Can somebody help me? I am new and not sure what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As AdamKG mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303584/how-to-reenter-a-pre-existing-django-app#comment13260375_10303584) -

> It depends on what docs you were following, but you're probably looking for source
>
> ```
> ~/path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
> ```

Comment: What happened why is this voted down? This is the true answer

Comment: I only posted this answer to notify other folks looking for answer to the same issue can find it. I also attached AdamKG in the answer to let them know who gave the answer. I intention was not to steal the answer. If that is why I have been banned then I can delete the answer if u want

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to activate an existing virtualenv: in your terminal, navigate to your django project folder and then type

`pipenv shell`

Venv should now be active.