# django wont show up in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to use `virtualenv`.
I installed it on my ubuntu system followed simple steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066681/django-installation-first-time) 
but when I activate my virtual environment and try to do

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

it throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I tried to see if django is accessible from my virtual env so it tried to

```
$ python 
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

and the same `import django` works fine out of the virtualenv.

I also tried to delete the `django` folder from root python setup and reinstalling it. but all in vain, the problem is still the same. What should I do now ?

PS: I tried to run `easy_install Django` & `easy_install django` gazillion times from the virtual env everytime it says django is already their.

PPS: I dont know if it is of importance but their was a `django` installation present prior doing all this in the system.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install Django; pip freeze` to see the details?

Comment: The following info would be useful: OS version, python version?

Comment: pip freeze shows Django==1.6.1 while virtualenv activated and its ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit and Python 2.7.3

Comment: and while `pip install Django` it says
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...

Comment: take a look at the system path to see if you are using the correct python of the virtualenv. do: import sys; print sys.path and check if the virtualenv path is included

Comment: @Udy yes its not included. how to include that ?

Comment: try instead of activate the virutalenv just using the python of the virtualenv. lets sat that virtualenv folder name is ve. then use ve/bin/python

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you mean. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: instead of activating the virtualenv, just use its python executalbe direct

Answer (score 0):

Check your `manage.py`, the first line needs to define the python executable, usually `#!/usr/bin/env python`. This should be the path to the python executable in your `virtualenv` and not to the global executable. If you had installed `Django` system wide this wouldn't be a problem.

Just in case

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Django is running system wide, thats why I cant understand the problem. Its not letting me install another django in the virtualenv nor it is taking the old django path.

Comment: How about activating the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

[Adding this info for Windows users who hit the same problem]

If you're running into this problem on Windows then make sure that your virtual env is active (your prompt will be something like `(venv) d:\myproject`) and that you're running python.exe explicitly.

On the latter point, do not run py.exe (the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#launcher) introduced in 3.3) or rely on a .py file association to run Python. Both of those will run a version of Python outside of your virtual env and therefore will have the wrong site-packages.

If your virtual env has django 1.8.6 but your core Python installation does not have django, then:

- `python -c "import django;print(django.get_version())"` will work and print `1.8.6`
- `py -c "import django;print(django.get_version())"` will fail with "`ImportError: No module named django`"