# Error downloading django

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I am trying to install Django and have run into an error. This has been a consistent error for me, something I have not been able to figure out how to solve. I am on a mac.

```
Installing collected packages: Django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
        root=options.root_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
        **kwargs
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
        ensure_dir(destdir)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
        os.makedirs(path)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'
```

Comment: The error is, that you do not have sufficient permission to install django in the default location. Its better to install django inside a virtualenv. That way, you wont run into permission issues. Also, the packages, etc are local to specific project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066681/django-installation-first-time

Comment: Also take a look at pyenv https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv which lets you comfortably install and manage python versions and virtual environments. You should never build on your native mac python.

Answer (score 1):

as karthikr said, you need

```
virtualenv project_env
cd project_env
. bin/activate
sudo pip install Django
```